# Google Analytics Issue for auto track event `in_app_purchase`

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, google-analytics-4, google-analytics-firebase, facebook-unity-sdk

We are facing an issue tracking an event named `in_app_purchse` Normally this event is auto-tracked by the Firebase Analytics event when the user makes any purchase for our game.

However, we are not able to verify it, even using Debug View or Realtime Analytic Dashboard.

while other auto-track events like `ad_rewarded` **we can verify** via debug view or real-time analytics dashboard.

we have checked Normal App logs using logcat. over there we found a log with `FirebaseSessions Sessions SDK disabled. Events will not be sent.` after that, we run these terminal commands to get verbose logs from Firebase.

```
adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
adb shell setprop log.tag.FA-SVC VERBOSE
adb logcat -v time -s FA FA-SVC
```

after that when we start IAP Purchase as a user from our game we get this logs

```
02-28 14:45:19.245 D/FA-SVC  (31561): Log and bundle. event: in_app_purchase(\_iap)
02-28 14:45:19.247 V/FA-SVC  (31561): Checking account type status for ad personalization signals
02-28 14:45:19.247 D/FA-SVC  (31561): Turning off ad personalization due to account type
02-28 14:45:19.248 D/FA-SVC  (31561): Marking in-app purchase as real-time
02-28 14:45:19.249 D/FA-SVC  (31561): Log and bundle processed. event, size, time_ms: in_app_purchase(\_iap), 1447, 4
```

Once we complete the purchase successfully we get these logs [Firebase log for `in_app_purchase` (github.com)](https://gist.github.com/PAHeartBeat/efbc88fda26f3f9d072a9e965e6abdd8)

These are all logs we are receiving on Log Cat, still the `in_app_purchse` event we are unable to verify the event using Firebase /GA4 debug view or RealTime Dashboard.

**Build Environment Info:**

1. Game Engine: Unity 2023.3.10f1 and Unity 2023.3.31f1
2. Game Target: Android (Google Play Store)
3. Firebase SDK: Unity SDK 11.2.0, 11.4.0, 11.6.0

**Testing Device:**

1. Platform: Android
2. OS Version: Android 13, Android 14

**Note:**

- The same setup and same code working fine with iOS
- We have redacted a few logs to be within the post-limit
- Some data in the log we have replaced with X.

Thanks in advance.

We have tried a few things like

1. update/Downgrade Firebase Unity SDK in unity and down
2. Double verified the Firebase Configs
3. Change Unity Version